# Codeigniter database connection error

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, error-handling

I have a curious problem...

Using Codeigniter I've redesigned my website on a test domain and hosting package, and today I have copied all files over to my other domain and hosting package, changed my database configurations (they are 100% correct) - and I'm getting this error:

A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346

I shouldn't have to change any other setting values in any files as it's still working on my test domain, just not on the other one... - are there any other configuration settings I've forgot to switch aside from main 'application/config/database.php'

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| DATABASE CONNECTIVITY SETTINGS
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file will contain the settings needed to access your database.
|
| For complete instructions please consult the 'Database Connection'
| page of the User Guide.
|
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| EXPLANATION OF VARIABLES
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|
|   ['hostname'] The hostname of your database server.
|   ['username'] The username used to connect to the database
|   ['password'] The password used to connect to the database
|   ['database'] The name of the database you want to connect to
|   ['dbdriver'] The database type. ie: mysql.  Currently supported:
                 mysql, mysqli, postgre, odbc, mssql, sqlite, oci8
|   ['dbprefix'] You can add an optional prefix, which will be added
|                to the table name when using the  Active Record class
|   ['pconnect'] TRUE/FALSE - Whether to use a persistent connection
|   ['db_debug'] TRUE/FALSE - Whether database errors should be displayed.
|   ['cache_on'] TRUE/FALSE - Enables/disables query caching
|   ['cachedir'] The path to the folder where cache files should be stored
|   ['char_set'] The character set used in communicating with the database
|   ['dbcollat'] The character collation used in communicating with the database
|                NOTE: For MySQL and MySQLi databases, this setting is only used
|                as a backup if your server is running PHP < 5.2.3 or MySQL < 5.0.7
|                (and in table creation queries made with DB Forge).
|                There is an incompatibility in PHP with mysql_real_escape_string() which
|                can make your site vulnerable to SQL injection if you are using a
|                multi-byte character set and are running versions lower than these.
|                Sites using Latin-1 or UTF-8 database character set and collation are unaffected.
|   ['swap_pre'] A default table prefix that should be swapped with the dbprefix
|   ['autoinit'] Whether or not to automatically initialize the database.
|   ['stricton'] TRUE/FALSE - forces 'Strict Mode' connections
|                           - good for ensuring strict SQL while developing
|
| The $active_group variable lets you choose which connection group to
| make active.  By default there is only one group (the 'default' group).
|
| The $active_record variables lets you determine whether or not to load
| the active record class
*/

$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = '79.170.40.242';
$db['default']['username'] = 'xxxxxx';
$db['default']['password'] = 'Xxxxxx';
$db['default']['database'] = 'xxxxxx';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;


/* End of file database.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/database.php */
```

Comment: post your database.php config file, an sure it's a database.php param wrong that produces that error, like password, or db name, or user or host

Comment: @sbaaaang As requested... Aside from username, password and database variables there is no difference from the same file on my test domain (which is working)

Comment: are you using different host for your db? why not 127.0.0.1? is somewhere else located the db i mean?

Comment: if you not using 127.0.0.1 host for your db you have to check if your db host can be called from outside the host itself i guess

Comment: @sbaaang It's same host, different package just... I changed pconnect and db_debug settings to false... The database connected OK, but suddenly none of my Model's database queries were working...

Comment: yeah but if your codeigniter app is on same host you have to use 127.0.0.1 as db host :P

Comment: Is the database hosted on a different server? If not the hostname should probably be `localhost`.

Comment: its seems to be hostname problem of your database.php file

Answer (score 1):

your database connection is failed. seems your database server is remote, so check out 2 items:

1- incoming port access for number 3306 (mysql port)

2- access mysql user for all foreign incoming host (see more: [mysql adding user manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html))